# How to write the expression for first order differential operator in Mathematica?

Tags: operators

How to write the expression for first order differential operator in Mathematica?
What I mean to say that I want to evaluate

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x)=f'(x)+f(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}.$$

I am struggling with the last term format i.e., $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.

Example:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}e^{ax}=ae^{ax}+e^{ax}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$

where $a=a(y)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is first order differential operator.

Please find the definition of first order differential operator here in the accepted answer: [Do derivatives of operators act on the operator itself or are they "added to the tail" of operators?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55773/do-derivatives-of-operators-act-on-the-operator-itself-or-are-they-added-to-the)

Comment: An operator needs something to operate on, right? So what does $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ on its own mean, computationally wise?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55773/do-derivatives-of-operators-act-on-the-operator-itself-or-are-they-added-to-the  Got the definition from the given link. Please check the accepted answer.

Comment: Check the notebook or pdf [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262223580_Symbolic_FAQ), subsection "Some noncommutative algebraic manipulation". The first example defines a `differentialOperate` function that I think has the features you want.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Will you please comment on this link https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265866/second-order-differential-operator-in-mathematica